# Spring with websocket and session interceptor + Tomcat = problem

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am facing weird problem. I am developing web application based on Spring Boot with WebSockets. I need to track anonymous web socket connections, therefore I am using custom `Principal` implementation which I am creating in custom `DefaultHandshakeHandler -> determineUser` method. To create such `Principal` object, I need some data from httpsession, therefore I am using `HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor` to fill `Map<String, Object> attributes` attribute in mentioned method.

Everything works like a charm, until I switch application packaging from JAR (using embeded Tomcat) to WAR and deploy it on standalone Tomcat. Suddenly, attribute `attributes` is empty as if WS connection is using different session than HTTP connection and therefore `HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor` will not pass required attributes. Any ideas, why it is behaving differently?

A few parts of the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/ws");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("ws-endpoint")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new AnonymousHandshakeHandler())
                .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor())
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Custom handshake handler:

```
public class AnonymousHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
        if (principal == null) {
            SessionData sd = (SessionData) attributes.get(AppVariables.MODEL_PARAM_SESSION);
            if (sd != null){
                principal = new AnonymousPrincipal();
                ((AnonymousPrincipal) principal).setName(sd...);
            }
        }
        return principal;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Using custom handshake interceptor I can see that WS connections have different session IDs. That explains empty attributes, but why? Why requests on embeded Tomcat are using the same session but on standalone Tomcat they are creating new session on every request?

Handshake interceptor:

```
public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
            Map attributes) throws Exception {
        if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
            ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
            System.out.println(session.getId());
            attributes.put(AppVariables.MODEL_PARAM_SESSION, session.getAttribute(AppVariables.MODEL_PARAM_SESSION));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
            Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. It consisted of two problems + my stupidity:

1. I am using `<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none" />` and I forgot about it. That is why every request was generating new session (sameSite without https was not creating JSESSIONID cookie).
2. My proxy was not set up well. That is why my `AnonymousHandshakeHandler` was not used. See: [link](https://forum.mattermost.org/t/solved-apache2-reverseproxy-with-websocket-https/437/3)